# Plotly Error : OSError: 522: client socket timeout

Tags: python, plotly

I was trying to plot a figure using plotly in Python3. The figure was generated but on using `fig.show(renderer='png',width=800,height=800)` I got an error `OSError: 522: client socket timeout` including that it wasn't able to connect to the orca server.

I have looked up the GitHub issues on similar problems but found nothing specific to this exact case and the solutions didn't work for me.

Please help me out. TIA.

Comment: Having this same problem!